# Google Container Registry - unauthorized, struggling to authenticate

Tags: docker, authentication, google-container-registry

Recently got a new Mac, and now I am struggling to push docker containers to GCR - receiving the error:

```
unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you 
may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in:
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

Commands that led to this error:

```
docker build -t our-node-container ./
docker tag our-node-container gcr.io/our-gcp-project/our-grc-images-directory
docker push gcr.io/our-gcp-project/our-grc-images-directory
```

Confirming that:

- I have a GCP account with billing, have enabled the Container Registry API and installed Cloud SDK, and have Docker installed.
- I have authenticated with `gcloud auth login`, which opened a window where I selected my email address associated with the GCP account. It led to this page.

[image]

and afterwards, I ran `gcloud config set project our-gcp-project`. I have closed my terminal window and attempted to `docker push` again, but continue to get this `unauthorized` error. How else can I troubleshoot this in an effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

As is standard, we solved the issue just moments after posting the question. Rather than deleting the question, I'll post an answer incase anyone runs into same issue.

We simply missed the last step, which was to run `gcloud auth configure-docker` to update the config file in /home/.docker/config.json